# What is the meaning of Tuple[Any, Any]

Tags: python, tuples, type-hinting

when I read the source code of mnist, I find the code below. `Tuple[type1, type2, ...]` means that a tuple includes the types, such as `type1` `type2`. So why here double Any? Thank you for your answer!

```
    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> Tuple[Any, Any]:
        """
        Args:
            index (int): Index

        Returns:
            tuple: (image, target) where target is index of the target class.
```

Comment: Signifies a tuple with two items with no *reference* to a type.?

Comment: Where are you getting the mnist dataset from?

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is due to neither `image` nor `target` (which is what this function returns) do not have a strict type definition. Any is the same as "We accept any non-type defined value"

Answer (score 0):

> So why here double Any?

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple) states

> Tuple[X, Y] is the type of a tuple of two items with the first item of type X and the second of type Y

The return value type hint, `... -> Tuple[Any, Any]`, is saying that the function will return a tuple with **two** items and no *guarantee* of a type.  Maybe the author didn't want that limitation.